# Generation of multipage pdf in R shiny

Tags: r, pdf, shiny, gridextra

I am facing some problem in generating pdf from the output. Lets have a look on my code.
`

```
pdfTitle<- as.character(format(Sys.Date(),"%A"))
  #Report generator
  output$export1 <- downloadHandler(
    #filename is a default argument of downloadHandler function. A string of the filename, including extension or a function that returns such a string..
    filename <- function() {
      paste("report-", Sys.Date(), ".pdf")
    },
    #content is a also default argument of downloadHandler function. A function that takes a single argument "file" that is a file path (string) of a nonexistent temp file, and writes the content to that file path. 
    content <- function(file) {
      tab <- tableGrob(mtcars)
      plot <- createPlot(mtcars[1],mtcars[2])
      pdf(file, onefile = FALSE,title = pdfTitle,paper = "a4")
      #paste the saved reactive values as pdf grid. grid.arrange() function will manage the grids.
      grid.arrange(plot,tab)
      #Terminate the command
      dev.off()
    }
  )
```

`
This download handler should generate a pdf with a plot and a table. As I have mentioned **onefile = False** the pdf will generate two different pages for plot and and table. But it's not working. The pdf is looking like the photo below.

[image]

How can I solve the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the issue has nothing to do with Shiny. Indeed, I would expect you would end up with exactly the same result if you run the "contents" part from the console.

More to the point, `onefile` set to FALSE is meant to generate multiple pdf files, not a single pdf file with more than one page. You should achieve what you have in mind with something like this:

```
    content <- function(file) {
      tab <- tableGrob(mtcars)
      plot <- createPlot(mtcars[1],mtcars[2])

      multipage <- marrangeGrob(grobs = list(tab, plot), nrow = 1, ncol = 1)

      ggplot2::ggsave(plot = multipage,
                filename = file,
                device = "pdf",
                width = 210,
                height = 297,
                units = "mm") # measures used for A4 format
    }
```

Cannot test fully as I do not have your `createPlot` function, but hope this helps.